# Json data displays on browser but returns error (500 : Internal server error) via HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get a json data at   "http://www.my currency.net/service/rates"    which contains a valid json data as I confirmed using my browser but returns an error 500 when I try to get the page using HttpUrlConnection. See screenshot of my code below;  Note: I have been using the code to get a success response from same url but it suddenly started returning Internal Server Error.

public JSONObject MakeHttpRequest() {

try {

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.mycurrency.net/service/rates");

        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");

        httpCon.connect();

        Log.d("cryptox", String.valueOf(httpCon.getResponseCode() + " : " + httpCon.getResponseMessage() + " : "+ httpCon.getErrorStream()));

        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream());

  //CREATE A BUFFERED READER TO CONVERT THE BYTES inputStream to char BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        jsonString = null;

        try{
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            jsonString = sBuilder.toString();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ProtocolException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

LOGCAT

> 06-05 14:24:02.249 23278-23437/com.cyptoxchange.cryptox D/cryptox: 500
>   : Internal Server Error :
>   buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource@5f6823).inputStream()
>   06-05 14:24:02.249 23278-23437/com.cyptoxchange.cryptox W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.mycurrency.net/service/rates
>   06-05 14:24:02.253 17887-17887/? I/: service_to_fd shell:cat
>   /proc/23278/stat 06-05 14:24:02.255 17887-17887/? I/: subprocess
>   creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=23717 06-05 14:24:02.271
>   17887-23718/? I/: post waitpid (pid=23717) status=0000 06-05
>   14:24:02.287 23278-23437/com.cyptoxchange.cryptox W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>   06-05 14:24:02.287 23278-23437/com.cyptoxchange.cryptox W/System.err: 
>   at
>   com.cyptoxchange.cryptox.HttpHandler.MakeHttpRequest(HttpHandler.java:32)

Any help with the cause of this will be much appreciated. Thanks.!

Comment: can you post your `code`, what do you tried !

Comment: probably you missed added in Accept:application/json header in the request, just a guess.

Comment: The post now contains my code

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with my server. the https url gives me a 500 error in the browser. But my server is using the http url and still getting a 500 error